# no alert after firebase called

Tags: javascript, jsp, firebase, alert

I can't show alert after called firebase

```
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCnmZWNwp3CfjXDcDL5MADIej6GwvxWEtQ",
    authDomain: "dsmweb-ba185.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://dsmweb-ba185.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "dsmweb-ba185.appspot.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  alert('asdf');
</script>
```

This is my source code, and what is wrong?

something happend in "  firebase.initializeApp(config);  "

Comment: Have you checked for error messages in the console?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/jujasim/1/edit?html,js,console